# div layout with float property

Tags: css, html

I want to achieve following layout:
[image]

with following code:

```
<div class="m">
    <div class="l"></div>
    <div class="r">
        <div class="r1"></div>
        <div class="r2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS look like this:

```
div.m{
    ...
    width: 100%;
}
div.m div.l{
    float: left;
    ...
}
div.m div.r{
    float: right;
    ...
}
div.mainMenu div.r1{
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    ...
}
div.mainMenu div.r2{
    position: relative;
    right: 65px;
    ...
}
```

which results to:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `top: 0` on **r2**?

Comment: @lorenzo-s: Yes, I have. Same result.

Comment: Ok, so try using `position: relative` on **r** and change to `position: absolute` on **r1** and **r2**, leaving `top: 0` on both.

Comment: @lorenzo-s: Works perfectly. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `position: relative` on **r** and change to position: absolute on **r1** and **r2**, leaving `top: 0` on both.

Ba careful, in this way the content **r** will be extended below **r1** and **r2**. If this is a problem, to avoid this, play with **r** `padding-right`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem perfectly. No, div `r` won't have any other content than these divs.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/xn8Ks/

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `position:absolute; top:0px;` for r1 and r2.
http://jsfiddle.net/Zdkdp/2/

```
div{
    height:100px;
}
div.m{
    border:1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
div.r{
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:33%;
}
div.r1, div.r2{
    border:1px solid red;
}
div.l{
    float: left;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:33%;
}
div.r{
    float: right;
}
div.r2{
    position:absolute;
    right:65px;
    top:0px;
}
div.r1{
    position:absolute;
    width:60px;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;

}
```

Comment: Actually this makes `r1` and `r2` to be positioned according to the screen, not `r` div. `r` div has to have `position:relative` like lorenzo-s wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong and the position of .r2 is to be expected. You need to set a negative top value for .r2. The negative top value is equal the height of .r1. So if `.r1 { height: 50px;}` then `.r2 { top: -50px; }`. Another option would be to float .r1 and .r2 instead of positioning them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original code, I made [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TnTYe/) that achieves the layout you've drawn.

The borders and colors in that fiddle are for demonstration purposes, of course.

The resulting html:

```
<div class="m">
    <div class="l">Left</div>
    <div class="r">Right
        <div class="r1">R1</div>
        <div class="r2">R2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

The clearfix div is there so you won't have to give a specific height to the things above it, making sure `m` has the correct height no matter what.

And the CSS:

```
div.m {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 100%;
}
div.m div.l{
    border: 2px solid green;
    float: left;
}
div.m div.r {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.r1, div.r2 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```